# Regex in C# to process a text

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to remove some text and keep only small text from the string.
Actually I am very new to regex, I have read an article and did not get it very well.
Here is an example of my text (every line in separate string object)

```
2015-03-08 10:30:00     /user841/column-width
2015-03-08 10:30:01     /user849/connect
2015-03-08 10:30:01     /user262/open-level2-price/some other text
2015-03-08 10:30:01     /user839/open-detailed-quotes
```

I want to process them using regex in c# and have the following output:

```
column-width
connect
open-level2-price/some other text
open-detailed-quotes
```

I have used the following line to do that but it throws an exception:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(line, @"*./user\d+/*.");
```

The Exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'parsing `"*./user\d+/*."` - Quantifier `{x,y}` following nothing.'

could anyone help please!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You say “I am trying to remove some text”. How are you doing that? Why did you think it didn't work? You tagged this “C#” but I don't see any C# code here. SO is a question-and-answer site and “could anyone help?” [is not a question we can answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/).

Comment: You don't need Regex for this

Comment: @DourHighArch I have edited the question, please re-read the edits. :)

Comment: Replace  `^.*/` with nothing.

Comment: @maccettura actually I don't guarantee the text I want to don't have any slash, so that is maybe easier to do using regex.

Comment: The error is because `*  <-- Quantifies nothing
     . /user \d+ /* .` And this is suspicious `/*` because it matches only like `//////` I'm taking a guess you meant `.*/user\d+/.*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you get is caused by the fact that you try to quantify the start of the pattern, which is considered an error in a .NET regex. Perhaps, you meant to use `.*` instead of the `*.` (to match any 0+ chars greedily, as many as possible), but it is certainly not what you need judging by the expected results.

You need

```
/user\d+/(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2Fuser%5Cd%2B%2F%28.*%29&i=2015-03-08%2010%3A30%3A00%20%20%20%20%20%2Fuser841%2Fcolumn-width%0D%0A2015-03-08%2010%3A30%3A01%20%20%20%20%20%2Fuser849%2Fconnect%0D%0A2015-03-08%2010%3A30%3A01%20%20%20%20%20%2Fuser262%2Fopen-level2-price%2Fsome%20other%20text%0D%0A2015-03-08%2010%3A30%3A01%20%20%20%20%20%2Fuser839%2Fopen-detailed-quotes)

**Details**:

- `/user` - a literal substring `/user`
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits (use `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option to only match ASCII digits with `\d` in a .NET regex)
- `/`  - a literal `/`
- `(.*)` - A *capturing* group #1 that matches any 0+ chars other than a newline (replace `*` with `+` to match at least 1 char).

[image]

C#:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"/user\d+/(.*)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Regex, just split on the `'/'` character and use the last index of the array (using LINQ):

```
string inputString = "2015-03-08 10:30:01     /user262/open-level2-price";
inputString.Split('/').Last();
```

Split returns an array of strings, in your case with the sample input above the string array would look like:

```
array[0] = "2015-03-08 10:30:01     "
array[1] = "user262"
array[2] = "open-level2-price"
```

You indicate you always want the last part so just use LINQ to take the `.Last()` index of the array.

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1EAx0a)

Comment: Yes that is a good point, but the problem is  I don't guarantee the text I want to don't have any slash.

Comment: @O-BL I'm confused, your regex expression specifically looks for slashes. If you can't guarantee slashes will be there then how would your regex work?

Comment: the input string maybe something like this `2015-03-08 10:30:01     /user262/open-level2-price/some other text` and the output sould be like this `open-level2-price/some other text` , so the regular form is : the date then the "user" word then the user number.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense then

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of how to use the Regex.Replace static method.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/JuUF9E

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] lines = new string[] {
            "2015-03-08 10:30:00     /user841/column-width",
            "2015-03-08 10:30:01     /user849/connect",
            "2015-03-08 10:30:01     /user262/open-level2-price",
            "2015-03-08 10:30:01     /user839/open-detailed-quotes"
        };

        string pattern = @"(.*/.*/)(.*)";

        string replacement = "$2";

        foreach(var line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(line, pattern, replacement));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're trying to do this simple thing with regex, you just have to read the lines and split by the '\', them select the last index and that's it. For example, if you have that data in a file you can use something like this:

```
string newString = "";
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader('log.txt');
while(!sr.ReadLine)
{
   string[] splitted = sr.ReadLine().Split('/');
   if(splitted.Length > 0)
        newString += splitted[splitted.Length - 1];
}
sr.Close();
```

At the end, the newString variable will contains what you want. Otherwise you can add every line in a list if you will do some with the data.

Answer (score 0):

How about using  [Look around](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444)

```
var line = "2015-03-08 10:30:01     /user839/open-detailed    otes/dsada/dsa/das/dsadsa";

//  dsadsa
var match = Regex.Match(line, @"(?!.*/).*").Value;
```

Comment: that gives me an error. Actually @WiktorStribiżew already answered the question. thank you. :)

Comment: Update, was missing "Match"

Comment: Thanks for help, I think the output string should be `open-detailed    otes/dsada/dsa/das/dsadsa`